# HTML whitespace after footer?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have developed this link and have a strange problem. A whitespace is present below the footer and I can't figure out ways to eliminate it. Can anybody help ?

Below is the link:
http://moviese.duncelab.com/channel.html

Comment: [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the `.recom-bot-row` element are too large and not clipped.

```
.recom-bot-row {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will fix it.

Comment: Fyi I spotted this within 10 seconds by just hitting 'Inspect Element' on the footer and hovering over elements to see their bounding boxes. Learn to use the debugging tools of a good browser like Chrome  ;)